# Removing Decimal from a column extracted from a dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset in an excel. I read the data into a dataframe "df" using read_excel.

During this process, I observed that col1 from df is providing decimals, when it should only have numbers with only 4 digits.

So, I have two questions here:

1. Why is it returning a decimal when the source of the data does not have any decimals
2. How can I remove the decimals in the result column

I have tried astype(int) and astype(float)

Assumed the reason it is providing decimals could be because of a few empty values. So, used fillna(0)

```
df_A = pd.read_excel("path\filename.xls")


Data = {

"A" : df_A['col1'].fillna(0)

(Also tried "A" : df_A['col1'].astype(int))

}

df_B = pd.DataFrame(Data_A)
```

Expected... column values of "5124, 5487, 9487, 3598"
Actual results.. column values of "5124.0, 5487.0, 9487.0, 3598.0"

Comment: Since df_A is a dataframe, you can fillna and then convert the column to int. df_A['col1'] = df_A['col1'].fillna(0).astype(int)

Comment: .fillna(0).astype(int) together is not working. " invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' Getting this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since df_A is a dataframe, you can fillna and then convert the column to int.

```
df_A['col1'] = df_A['col1'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Since you are getting the error `invalid literal for int() with base 10:` with the above code, it means that there are some non-numeric values in your data which can not be converted to int. Use pd.to_numeric to coerce those values to NaN and then use the above code.

```
df_A['col1'] = pd.to_numeric(df_A['col1'], errors = 'coerce')
df_A['col1'] = df_A['col1'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: @RoopaDivya, that's great! You can mark an answer as accepted - click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green. Happy coding!