# pandas read_excel data types options

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

I'm using the Pandas module in Python to read an excel file and generate a csv file. I noticed that in the column where the cell format was marked "General" and the content was the number 1 or not filled in, the result in the csv file was 1.0 instead of 1 as I had hoped. If all the values in the excel table were filled (there were no empty cells), the result was as I hoped. How to use the read_excel method in Pandas so that empty cells do not affect the creation of the decimal place when creating a DATAFRAME?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56191072/removing-decimal-from-a-column-extracted-from-a-dataframe-using-pandas) post might help with your problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: import pandas as pd
read_file = pd.read_excel (import_file_path, sheet_name=0)
export_file_path = csv_directory+"/"+filename+".csv"
read_file.to_csv (export_file_path, index = None, header=True, decimal=',', sep=';', encoding='utf-8-sig', mode='x')